# How do I choose the best nonstick pan or coating, for high heat on an electric cook top?

Tags: non-stick

After reading [Nonstick Pan Ruined in High Heat?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/99510) and [Why did my Zwilling Aluminium pan cookware surface corrode just after 1 month?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/115285), I'm still afraid of accidentally buying shoddy non stick coating or pan , damaging it, and wasting money.

What are some tips or advice to choose the most reliable, durable non stick coating or pan? Are there any keywords or chemicals to look for or avoid? I'm using this pan just on [my Frigidaire 30" electric induction cook top](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/115453), not inside the oven.

Comment: What kind of "high heat" are you talking about ? non-stick teflon pans will work at high heat (ie high enough for bacon for example)

Comment: The difference between pans is not the Teflon but the care of application and the other construction features of the pan.   Factors like the surface preparation and thickness of the Teflon layer.